# Deleting a database in SQL Server does not delete the .mdf and .ldf files

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I created my database in SSMS, I selected the destination to be `D:` drive. Now when I delete the database, the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files of the deleted database are still on the `D:` drive. Why?

Is this a normal behavior? I am running out of disk space and I need to get rid of the databases I am not using but the disk space of `D:` drive is still an issue because the files are not being deleted properly.

Should I just manually delete the `.mdf`, `.ldf` files?

Comment: [Dropping a database deletes the files, unless that database is offline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=Dropping%20a%20database%20deletes%20the,manually%20by%20using%20Windows%20Explorer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs :

> Dropping a database deletes the database from an instance of SQL Server and deletes the physical disk files used by the database. If the database or any one of its files is offline when it is dropped, the disk files are not deleted. These files can be deleted manually by using Windows Explorer. To remove a database from the current server without deleting the files from the file system, use sp_detach_db.

I suspect the database was offline so the files weren't deleted.